# What is a Segon?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology, unit-of-measure

This morning I asked my Alexa device

> what is the arctangent of 1?

to which it replied:

> Inverse tangent of 1 is 0.0175.

Now, this answer seemed rather strange to me, as I was expecting 45° or $\frac{\pi}{4}$radians so I asked:

> What unit of measurement are you using for angles?

and it replied:

> Segons.

I've tried googling Segon, and found it is an SI unit of time but I've never heard of it before. My question is: is "Segon" a valid unit of angle measure, and if so, where did it come from?

Comment: Since $\tan(1^\circ) \approx 0.0175$ it sounds like Siri might have misunderstood the question, and also use degrees.

Comment: "Segons" could be "seconds" - a second is 1/60th of a minute, which is 1/60th of a degree.

Comment: I think @Magma is correct and Alexa is answering the wrong question. The transcripts clearly show it answering "inverse tangent" but its giving tangent.